# Cannot Reach Primary Domain On Lan

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, exchange, internal-dns, dns-zone

So i created a website for a client and now they cannot get to their www.domain.com when they are connected to their LAN. The site is hosted on our server.
They have an exchange server and I added an A record for WWW to point to the new ip.
When i traceroute www.domain.com it points to the correct ip but times out
when I traceroute domain.com it points to the exchange server ip and completes.

Any ideas on what this could be would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: As it sounds, DNS is working, since www.domain.com gets the correct IP. You say the trace route fails. Can you ping the IP address? If not, it's still no guarantee something's wrong: could be that ICMP simply isn't allowed outside the LAN. Firewall in place? Can you access the site on IP address directly, not using the FQDN?

Comment: If they have a Windows domain on their LAN and the name of the Windows domain is the same "domain.com" as their public web site, then they will not be able to go to "domain.com" to reach their web site, since internal DNS **must** point that to domain controllers. Sometimes that stops the web site from working internally because the web site is designed to redirect www.domain.com to just domain.com. Do they have a Windows domain and does the Windows domain name match their public web site domain name?

Comment: I agree that traceroute (and ICMP in general) is not usually diagnotiscally useful outside of the internal LAN/WAN.

Comment: When i try and ping the IP address of our server on their LAN, it times out. They also have a SonicWall but im not sure thats the traceroute doesnt pass through the SonicWall IP.